# Go back to previous app

Tags: android

app A call `startActivity` to app B , app B verify and go back to app A . how to implement this .

app A :

```
Intent intent;
PackageManager packageManager = GameLanuchActivity.this.getPackageManager();
intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example");
if(null == intent) {
    //todo not exit.        
} else {
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example","com.example.XeaAuthActivity"));
    GameLanuchActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

app B :

called `quit`after some logic , it return to the HomeActivity of app B , not app A .

```
private void quit() {
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_right_in, R.anim.push_right_out);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

to app A.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
finishAffinity();
```

But it apply in only API level 16 above..